# Перетаскивание родительской формы за дочернюю форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма без заголовка. Как её таскать я разобрался.
Данный код перехватывает сообщение о схваченном заголовке и форма делает вид, что её таскают за заголовок:

```
base.Capture = false; 
Message m = Message.Create(base.Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero); 
this.WndProc(ref m);
```

В родительской форме находится панель, в которую подключается другая форма.
При этом код на панель не работает. Он работает на форму. Если данный код прикрутить к дочерней форме, то она начинает таскаться внутри панели!

Можно ли отрихтовать данный код таким образом, чтобы при захвате дочерней панели передавалось сообщении о хватании заголовка родителя?!

Comment: Вы хотите перетаскивать форму зажав левую кнопку мыши на любом контроле на этой форме?

Comment: Я хочу перетаскивать родительскую форму зажав левую кнопку мыши на дочерней форме.

Comment: для этого кнопку надо сделать прозрачной для мыши. ниже я добавил ответ с примером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример: форму можно передвигать за любую точку, включая кнопку.
Если отключить checkbox, то кнопка перестанет быть прозрачной для мыши.
Поведение реализовано на основе наследников NativeWindow и может подключаться к формам и контролам.

```
 #r "System.Windows.Forms"

 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System;

 class Draggable : NativeWindow {
     public Draggable(Control c) { this.AssignHandle(c.Handle); }
     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
         base.WndProc(ref m);
         if (m.Msg == 0x84 && (int)m.Result == 0x1) m.Result = (IntPtr) 0x2;
     }
   }
 class HTTransparent : NativeWindow {
     public HTTransparent(Control c) { this.AssignHandle(c.Handle); }
     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
         if (m.Msg == 0x0084)          // WM_NCHITTEST
             m.Result = (IntPtr)(-1);    // HTTRANSPARENT
         else
             base.WndProc(ref m);
     }
 }
 var f = new Form();
 var d = new Draggable(f);
 var b = new Button() { Parent = f };
 var t = new HTTransparent(b);
 var c = new CheckBox() { 
           Text = "HTTransparent", 
           Parent = f, 
           Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, 
           Checked = true };
 c.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => { 
    if (!c.Checked) t.ReleaseHandle(); 
    else t.AssignHandle(b.Handle); 
    };
 f.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Дочерние панели можно сделать прозрачными для мыши, примерно так:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0084)            // WM_NCHITTEST
        m.Result = (IntPtr)(-1);    // HTTRANSPARENT
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```