# Как обратиться к TableLayoutPanel через элемент внутри него?

Tags: c#, winforms

А именно, что я имею в виду. Я создал свой контрол `MyTableLayoutPanel`, который почти полностью совпадает с базовым, за исключением трех переопределенных событий. Переопределил я их для того, что бы было возможно перемещать контрол контрол по форме, собственно вот код.

```
class MyTableLayoutPanel:TableLayoutPanel
{
    //точка перемещения
    Point DownPoint;
    //нажата ли кнопка мыши
    bool IsDragMode;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        DownPoint = mevent.Location;
        IsDragMode = true;
        base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        IsDragMode = false;
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        //если кнопка мыши нажата
        if (IsDragMode)
        {
            Point p = mevent.Location;
            //вычисляем разницу в координатах между положением курсора и "нулевой" точкой кнопки
            Point dp = new Point(p.X - DownPoint.X, p.Y - DownPoint.Y);
            Location = new Point(Location.X + dp.X, Location.Y + dp.Y);
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(mevent);
    }
}
```

Всё работает как нужно, контрол перемещается, никаких ошибок. Далее.
В `MyTableLayoutPanel` я помещаю картинки или кнопки. Собственно вопрос, как нажимая картинки, перемещать `MyTableLayoutPanel`, а не картинку или кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как таковой маршрутизации событий между родительскими и дочерними контролами в WinForms не предусмотрено, она есть только в WPF. Но можно частично сымитировать маршрутизацию событий от дочернего к родительскому и воспользоваться вот таким нехитрым приемом:

```
public partial class MyTableLayoutPanel:TableLayoutPanel
{
    public MyTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Подписываемся на событие добавления дочернего контрола
        this.ControlAdded += MyTableLayoutPanel_ControlAdded;
        // Подписываемся на событие удаления дочернего контрола
        this.ControlRemoved += MyTableLayoutPanel_ControlRemoved;   
    }
```

События [**Control.ControlAdded**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded(v=vs.110).aspx) и [**Control.ControlRemoved**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlremoved(v=vs.110).aspx) срабатывают, когда в контрол добавляются дочерние контролы. Воспользуемся этим чтобы не подписываться руками на события дочерних контролов для выполнения действий над контейнером.

```
    void MyTableLayoutPanel_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // Добавляем свои обработчики к нужным событиям дочернего контрола
        // когда он добавляется в контейнер
        e.Control.MouseUp += MouseUpHandler;
        e.Control.MouseDown += MouseDownHandler;
        e.Control.MouseMove += MouseMoveHandler;
    }

    void MyTableLayoutPanel_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // Не забываем отписать дочерний контрол от наших обработчиков при его удалении, 
        // чтобы не удерживать ссылку на объект дольше необходимого
        e.Control.MouseUp -= MouseUpHandler;
        e.Control.MouseDown -= MouseDownHandler;
        e.Control.MouseMove -= MouseMoveHandler;
    }
```

События основаны на делегатах, а делегат хранит ссылку на объект, метод которого в него передан, поэтому чтобы не получить утечку памяти, не забываем отписываться от событий, при удалении контрола из родительского контейнера. Также, в обработчике события `ContolAdded`, можно произвести дополнительную настройку свойств дочерних контролов.

Ну и напоследок описываем обработчики нужных нам событий для управления родительским контейнером.

```
    private void MouseUpHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs newArgs = new MouseEventArgs(
            e.Button, 
            e.Clicks, 
            ((Control)sender).Location.X+e.X,
            ((Control)sender).Location.Y+e.Y,
            e.Delta);
        OnMouseUp(newArgs);
    }
    // и так для каждого события, которое нужно передать в родительский контейнер
}
```

Если все сделано правильно, ваши дочерние контролы будут вызывать еще и обработчики родительского контейнера. Еще один нюанс, обработчик родительского контейнера должен аккуратно проверять кто именно его вызвал и переводить координаты из системы координат дочернего контрола в свою, если конечно он получает координаты в аргументах события и использует их. Тоже может касаться и других аргументов события, так что будьте внимательны при разработке логики таких принудительных обработчиков событий.

Также почитайте этот **[вопрос и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475596/198316)**, там предложено решение которое возможно подойдет и для ваших целей.

Еще один вариант решения, это перейти на WPF и использовать маршрутизацию событий, которая там доступна без шаманства "из коробки".

Comment: Не совсем понял Ваш пример. Т.е. мне нужно добавить еще 4 обработчика события к моим, которые уже есть ? И что у Вас понимается под UseControl для моего примера, дочерний элемент или родительский? Поясните пожалуйста, пока не разобрался.

Comment: надеюсь так стало понятнее. вобщем да, идею вы уловили, раз событие не может быть передано, вызываем обработчик поймав его в другом контроле. Только не вписывайте в подключаемый обработчик вызовы `OnSomthing(EventArgs e)` т.к. он инициирует событие и это приведет к переполнению стека.

Comment: `this.ControlAdded += MyTableLayoutPanel_ControlAdded;` допустим если дочерний элемент обычная кнопка, у меня должно быть `this.MyButtonAdded += MyTableLayoutPanel_MyButtonAdded;` ? если да, то кругом ошибки... что-то я не уловил..(

Comment: да нет, того кода который есть в примере достаточно. прямо в том виде как есть. Единственное надо заменить подписку на событие клик,  нужными вам подписками. Ну и хотя бы мельком взглянуть в MSDN в описание событий `ControlAdded` и `CotrolRemoved`

Comment: Прямо в том виде как есть - кучу ошибок вызывает.

Comment: this.MyButtonAdded += MyTableLayoutPanel_MyButtonAdded; - не надо переписывать название обработчиков. Их всего 2 и они уже написаны. единственное что нужно менять - подписки в обработчика ControlAdded и ControlRemoved, ну и дописать свои обработчики для этих событий

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40389/discussion-between---and-rdorn).