# Перемещение формы за любую часть

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так, чтобы перемещение формы осуществлялось не только за верхнюю границу, а за любую часть данной формы?

Comment: [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30184/4924596) есть несколько решений, используется WinAPI

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527892/198316 этот вариаент легко адаптируется для формы, форма ведь тоже контрол. Там же есть ссылка на еще одно решение с использованием WinAPI. Зависит от конечной цели

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо всем. Пройдя по ссылке Руслана Артамонова выбрал этот варинат. Все красиво отрабатывает:

```
 public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
 public const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
 [DllImport("User32.dll")]
 public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
 [DllImport("User32.dll")]
 public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form_MouseDown);  
}

void Form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{                        
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Опуская некоторые детали форма стала выглядеть вот так. С любого места формы, кроме контролов, можно перетащить на экране.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Можно через обработчик событий, при зажатии мышки на форме и перемещении мыши изменять свойство положения формы, т. е. прибавлять к координатам формы координаты смещения мыши, это если вам не подойдет вариант с `WinAPI`

Comment: Сейчас попробую этот вариант и отпишу как визуально выглядит.