# C# Перетаскивание формы за любой элемент. ( FormBorderStyle: None )

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, довольно давно использую несколько методов, приведу код ниже.
Возможно есть более гуманное решение этой задачи, поделитесь кодом.

```csharp
[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint WParam, uint LParam);

[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal extern static bool ReleaseCapture();

const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const uint DOMOVE = 0xF012;
const uint DOSIZE = 0xF008;
```

А в событие MouseDown элемента управления вставляем сл. код.

```csharp
ReleaseCapture();
PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
```

Данный вариант работает отлично, без зависаний, и мерцаний, возможно есть лучше решение?

Comment: а чем вам не нравится это решение, если оно работает? WinForms - оболочка над WinAPI, вы используете импорт WinAPI для управления WinAPI, в чем выражается негуманность? Вариант конечно есть, на основе нисходящей маршрутизации событий (описывал уже где-то [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527892/198316)), только кода в таком решении значительно больше и вероятность ошибки выше, оно вам надо?

Comment: Вам плюсик от меня , недостаток моего решения в том , что часто встречаются перегруженные интерфейсы, в таком случае приходиться создавать событие MouseDown для 5-10 элементов. Естественно создаю метод и вставляю его , не нравится именно гора однотипных событий.( возможно у меня старческий маразм)... а возможно есть молодые продвинутые, и с лучшими идеями .

Comment: На WinForms ничего лучше особо не придумаешь, во всяком случае в данном аспекте точно. WPF маршрутизацию событий "из коробки" умеет, но он далек от WinAPI и работает поверх DirectX. А тут уже сто лет ни чего не менялось, сторонние фреймворки типа DevExpress тоже ни чего особо не меняют, только добавляют своих тараканов вместе с рюшечками и красивостями. Там все упирается в реализацию WinAPI, если что-то сделать можно, но не было сделано - допиливают в сторонних фреймворках, если нельзя - значит нельзя.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        base.Capture = false;
        Message m = Message.Create(base.Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
        this.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Перетаскивание - Нужный элемент подписываем на событие зажатия клавиши мыши MouseLeftButtonDown и в обработчике вызываем `DragMove();`

```
public void DragWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        DragMove();
}
```

Ответ взят с: [Реализация стандартных кнопок и поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883305/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: В вопросе WinForms, вы дали ссылку на WPF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так все команды написанные в том ответе можно использовать и в коде Winforms, не?

Comment: @Andrew - не. В WinForms, по-крайней мере, нет метода `DragMove`.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вы хотите что-то вроде этого:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool isMousePress = false;
    private Point _clickPoint;
    private Point _formStartPoint;

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMousePress = true;
        _clickPoint = Cursor.Position;
        _formStartPoint = Location;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMousePress)
        {
            var cursorOffsetPoint = new Point( //считаем смещение курсора от старта
                Cursor.Position.X - _clickPoint.X,
                Cursor.Position.Y - _clickPoint.Y);

            Location = new Point( //смещаем форму от начальной позиции в соответствии со смещением курсора
                _formStartPoint.X + cursorOffsetPoint.X,
                _formStartPoint.Y + cursorOffsetPoint.Y);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMousePress = false;
        _clickPoint = Point.Empty;
    }
}
```