# Реализация стандартных кнопок и поведения

Tags: c#, wpf

Так как `Window` имеет `WindowStyle="None"`
необходимо воссоздать стандартные кнопки:

- Сворачивание приложения в трей
- Разворот во всё окно и обратно
- Выход из приложения
- Перетаскивание

Откуда эти поведения можно выдернуть ?

Или может у кого есть в загашнике реализация всего этого ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Сворачивание приложения в трей - `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;` + метод `Hide();`
- Разворот во всё окно и обратно - `WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;` (обратно: `WindowState = WindowState.Normal;`)
- Выход из приложения - `Close();`, либо что то более кардинальное (`Application.Current.Shutdown();`)
- Перетаскивание - Нужный элемент подписываем на событие зажатия клавиши мыши (`MouseLeftButtonDown`) и в обработчике вызываем `DragMove();`

Либо вовсе можно использовать `WindowChrome`, пример такого показан [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676221/220553).

---

**Использование `WindowChrome`**:

К примеру у нас есть простое окно, у которого заданы следующие параметры: `WindowStyle="None"` и `AllowsTransparency="True"`. Изначально оно по стандарту будет просто белое, без кнопок и каких либо элементов управления, как быть?

Добавляем для начала `WindowChrome`, делается это написанием нечто подобного:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Уже на данном этапе у нас будет возможность передвижения окна за "шапку", контекстное меню при клике по "шапке", а также элементы изменения размера со всех сторон.

Работа с `WindowChrome`:

- Если мы хотим изменить размер шапки, делаем это путем указания `CaptionHeight` с нужным размером у `<WindowChrome/>`.
- Если хотим изменить рамки "ресайза", то меняем `ResizeBorderThickness`.
- Если мы используем `WindowChrome` и затем устанавливаем кнопки (закрыть/свернуть/развернуть) там, где у нас `CaptionHeight`, то для их работы нужно будет установить `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`, иначе наши кнопки будут не активны.

Вот таким простым способом мы добавляем окну часть стандартного функционала.

Comment: Здорово, Спасибо! А можете что то добавить по воссозданию изменения размеров окна если добавил ему `AllowsTransparency="True"` ? Я как то делал, захватывал позицию мышки и от этого уже плясал, но там довольно всё громоздко было, вдруг есть что то более простое.

Comment: @Vipz Если без `WindowChrome`, то придется городить, если же используем хром, то читаем ответ.